# ~/.vimrcを毎回soしなければならない問題

Tags: vim

こんにちは。vimの設定で困っています。

themeのセッティングについてですが普通にvimを開くと

[image: ソース前]

のようになります。これだとテーマが反映されていません。なので毎回

```
:so ~/.vimrc
```

として以下のようにしています

[image: あと]

どうすれば`vim sample.txt`のようにいつでも下のように開けるのでしょうか？

Comment: ウィンドウのタイトルが "nvim" になっているので、使っているのは Neovim ではありませんか？

Comment: えーリアスでneovimに設定しています

Answer (score 2, accepted):

neovimの設定ファイルを作成し、sourceで`~/.vimrc`を読み込めばよいと思います。

【手順】

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/nvim/     #初回だけ
vi ~/.config/nvim/init.vim
```

【設定ファイルの内容】

```
execute 'source' expand('~/.vimrc')
```

Comment: `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` に `execute 'source' expand('~/.vimrc')` を追加、という認識であってますか？ちなみに、`/.vimrc` にプラグインとかを書いてたんですけどまさか間違ってましたか、、、

Comment: 解決しました！neovimの設定ファイルをいじるんですね、覚えておきます

Comment: vimの設定ファイルをnvimでも使いたいのだと思いました。vimとnvimで設定ファイルを一元管理するテクニックもいろいろとWebで公開されています。